# difference between .GetRootItem, .GetParent and .GetChildren in outlook?

Tags: outlook

can someone explain to me in the simplest way, the difference between .GetRootItem, .GetParent, and .GetChildren? Particularly on the last two. I've read the microsoft documentation, but I couldn't get my head wrap around it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.GetChildren will return all Items under the specified conversation.

.GetPartent will return specified conversation's parent.

.GetRootItems will return conversation all root item.

Comment: Hi Alina. Thanks for the input. but what is the meaning of .GetRootItem(1) ?

Comment: .GetRootItems  return only include root item not include items under root item. .GetRootItem(1) meaning of the first root item.